# Polyfills in 2019 for IE11

Tags: javascript, frontend, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

This is 2019, we would like to support IE11 when we don't have anything better to do of our time and I have to admit that I am a bit confused about all the polyfills available.

- `babel-polyfill` seems to recommend `core-js`
- `core-js`
- `es5-shim` and `es6-shim`

As far as I understand all those things are supposed to enable newer version of Ecmascript but not to patch the rest. I have a couple custom polyfills, e.g. to support CustomEvent.

I don't think it changes anything, but I am using:

- webpack 2.7.0
- babel 6.16

Right now at the top of my main script I have:

```
require('core-js');
```

But I still get:

```
Object doesn't support property of method 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)_a.Kr7pt1C'
```

Which seems to be mostly an unsupported Ecmascript iteration feature.

Any advice on what to do at the macro level of the problem?

## EDIT

The `Symbol.iterator` is actually by a missing "for ... of " polyfill.

## EDIT: SOLUTION

My full configuration is visible in this answer [Include node_modules directory in Babel 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044643/include-node-modules-directory-in-babel-7/57689106#57689106)

Comment: @Andreas very welcoming, thanks ;)    How is it supposed to be useful?

Comment: Just use babel and transpile the code into a version that IE11 understands.

Comment: I am investigating this option.

Comment: are you managed to get this work , ?

Comment: @Jayavel yes (last line of the question contains a link to my final configuration)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using Babel for transpilation, you can use the `@babel/preset-env` preset and set your target environment to be IE11*.

1. Install the preset: `yarn add @babel/preset-env --dev`
2. Configure your targets in your Babel config:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/presets-env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": {
          "ie": "11"
        }
      },
    }]
  ]
}
```

*From [the docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env)

> @babel/preset-env takes any target environments you've specified and checks them against its mappings to compile a list of plugins and passes it to Babel.

Comment: full of typos.... for me as well, e.g. imho should be `{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "ie": "11"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
` but: get problem with find and entries in IE11.... so doesnt even work for me

Comment: Targets.browsers is a string or array of strings. To specify browser targets in the way described above, it should be `"targets": { "ie": "11" }`

Answer (score 4):

In the [official documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/learn#iterators-forof), it says *"In order to use Iterators you must include the Babel [polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill/)."* You could try to install it with `npm install --save @babel/polyfill` and use it with `require("@babel/polyfill")` at the top of the entry point to your application.

> The polyfill is provided as a convenience but you should use it with [@babel/preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) and the [useBuiltIns option](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins) so that it doesn't include the whole polyfill which isn't always needed. Otherwise, we would recommend you import the individual polyfills manually.

You could also try to import `core-js/fn/symbol/iterator.js`.

Comment: importing `e-js/fn/symbol/iterator.js` in my `polyfills.ts` worked like a charm