# Include some node_modules directories in Babel 7

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, jsx

I have a dependency in `node_modules` that needs to be compiled through Babel. I don't manage to get Babel back to compiling after upgrading my stack.

Current versions:

- @babel/core 7.5.4
- webpack 2.7.0

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    context: path.resolve('resources/assets/js/'),
    entry: ['./index'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('public/js'),
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                include: [
                    path.resolve('resources/assets/js/'),
                    path.resolve('node_modules/mydep/'),
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules\/(?!mydep).+/,
                test: /\.js|jsx$/,
                use: { loader: 'babel-loader' }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve('./resources/assets/js/'),
            'node_modules'
        ]
    },
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
        ignored: [
            /node_modules([\\]+|\/)+(?!mydep)/,
            /\mydep([\\]+|\/)node_modules/
        ]
    }
};
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "debug": true,
      "useBuiltIns": "usage"
    }],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

The error I get at the top of first JSX tag :

```
ERROR in /var/www/node_modules/mydep/somedir/app/index.js
Module build failed (from /var/www/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /var/www/node_modules/mydep/somedir/app/index.js: Unexpected token (160:15)

  158 |         registerReducers();
  159 |         new SomeClass('acquisition');
> 160 |         return <SomeComponent />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got this to work.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "someproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "browserslist": "> 0.25% in DE, not dead",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "browserify": "^16.2.0",
    "core-js": "^3.1.4",
    "minify": "^3.0.5",
    "somedeps": "ssh://git@bitbucket.org:somedeps.git",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
    "webpack": "^4.35.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    context: path.resolve('resources/assets/js/'),
    entry: ['./index'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('public/js'),
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js|jsx$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            ["@babel/preset-env", {
                                useBuiltIns: 'entry',
                                corejs: 3
                            }],
                            "@babel/preset-react"
                        ],
                        plugins: [
                            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
                        ],
                        include: [
                            path.resolve('resources/assets/js/'),
                            path.resolve('node_modules/somedeps/'),
                        ],
                        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!somedeps).+/
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve('./resources/assets/js/'),
            'node_modules'
        ]
    },
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
        ignored: [
            /node_modules([\\]+|\/)+(?!somedeps)/,
            /\somedeps([\\]+|\/)node_modules/
        ]
    }
};
```

At the top of your app main file, here resources/assets/js/index.js, include:

```
require('core-js');
require('regenerator-runtime/runtime');
```

Answer (score -5):

I think this contradicts the philosophy of building js-code.

All packages in node_modules must be already built, because nobody, excluding package's author, doesn't know how to build this package.

If `mydep` is your package, I recommend to build it before publishing to npm. Else, you can fork it or build in postinstall scripts.

Comment: I was possible in previous versions, and basically I want to build it the same way as my current code. It's a way for me to factorize code between project, postinstall scripts would basically slow down my build process.

Comment: You can use prepublish script on your npm package. The second solution is adding your npm packages to your main projects by symlink. But If you have a lot of you own packages, you can explore monorepository  solutions. For example, https://rushjs.io/

Comment: You're thinking of TypeScript code as something that can't be used without compiling it to JavaScript. This is not always correct. Many compilation and execution environments can use TypeScript code directly.